# MySql INNER JOIN Query issues

Tags: mysql, utf-8, inner-join, latin1

I have been searching high and low to a solution for a "stupid" issue i am working with.

I have inherited a system from a former developer, and he was using LATIN1 as charset. Not much a problem, BUT i have always used UTF8, and now i need to make a INNER JOIN to a table with LATIN1 encoded data comparing TEXT field. This generates my issue, since i can not find a way to "compare" 2 textfields with eachother, since one is in UTF8 and the other in LATIN1

Is there any way around this issue, other than "changing the charset" for the LATIN1 tables.

Comment: Thanks to Vishal Zanzrukia for giving me a headup on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CAST` mysql function to achieve this.

for example,

```
SELECT CAST(_latin1'test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
```

reference link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html